# Both katalon and eclipse facing the issue while uploading a file on automation. Mentioned in detail below

Tags: selenium-webdriver, file-upload, automation, katalon-studio, awtrobot

```
package tools

import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.Keyword
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI

import java.awt.Robot
import java.awt.Toolkit
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent
import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.Keyword
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI

public class uploadFiles {

    @Keyword
    def uploadFile (TestObject to, String filePath) {
        WebUI.click(to)
        StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(filePath);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.delay(1000); //Millisecond 1 second delay only if needed
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.delay(1000); //Millisecond 1 second delay only if needed
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    }
}
```

Above code is placed in keywords folder in the project structure.

```
CustomKeywords.'tools.uploadFiles.uploadFile'(iWay_Product.findElement(By.cssSelector('input#fuDrivers')).click(),'D:\\UserImport_Template.xls')
Thread.sleep(2500) //Millisecond 2.5 second delay only if needed
//More files can be added here...
```

This above code has been used in the actual test cases. Always getting this below error.
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument

Comment: Can you post the rest of the error message? What line of code it is reffering to?

Comment: Can you please share me the upload functionality code either in Katalon or eclipse ide using selenium.
Whenever I run this code, While clicking "Browse button to upload any docx" I face this error.